# Получить достур к Mime заголовкам сообщения c# WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, mime

Есть клиент к WCF службе. 
Вызывается некий метод службы для отправки запроса. 
В своем распоряжении имею MessageInspector, который ловит исходящее сообщение и получаемый ответ. Пусть будет BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel).
Хочу узнать, как получить доступ к Mime заголовкам сообщения для их редактирования?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо понимать, что заголовок HTTP не является заголовком в понимании SOAP - это просто какая-то деталь реализации транспортного слоя.

Тем не менее, WCF умеет предоставлять доступ к подобным "деталям реализации". Это делается через свойства сообщения, а точнее - через `HttpRequestMessageProperty`.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,  System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    HttpRequestMessageProperty property;
    object propertyObj;
    if (request.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out propertyObj))
        property = (HttpRequestMessageProperty)propertyObj;
    else
        request.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, property = new HttpRequestMessageProperty());

    // Теперь делайте с property.Headers что хотите
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Действительно, получается обращаться к HTTP заголовкам!

А не подскажете, каким образом можно было добраться до заголовков, которые идут после Soap конверта?

Comment: @Eric это вы какие имеете в виду?

Comment: UPD:
@PaverMayorov Попробую объяснить на примере, который мне понятен при использовании HttpWebRequest и МТОМ.
При HttpWebRequest можно в заголовках добавить в сообщению необходимые части, получить RequestStream, записать в него необходимую Mime часть (Boundary, ContentIp, Content-Type), добавить байты соапа, а затем снова добавить необходимую Mime часть (Boundary, ContentIp, Content-Type + байты вложения), а затем простым Post отправить этот запрос. 
А можно ли чего-либо такого добиться с WCF?

Comment: @Eric ох... надо было сразу говорить что вы формат MTOM используете

Comment: @Eric нет, MTOM генерируется WCF в соответствии с https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/, настроек тут не предусмотрено

Comment: @PaverMayorov тогда каким образом встраивается вложение, просто заполняю xop Include, а остальное WCF сделает сам?

Comment: @Eric нет. Вы просто делаете массив байт - а WCF при сериализации создаст и xop Include, и часть с содержимым

Comment: @PaverMayorov внес некоторые изменения, однако вместо создания xop include, к сожалению, получаю в соапе свои байты в теге содержимого. Почему при сериализации не создался xop Include?
В биндинг поставил messageEncoding="Mtom"

Comment: @Eric вижу, вы поставили зеленую галочку. Это значит, что вы нашли в чем была последняя проблема? Может, расскажете?